# How to encrypt different parts of datastore with single key?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encryption

I'd like the encrypt information stored in the datastore in Google App Engine. I would like to do this with a key hardcoded into the program and not checked into source control, such that someone who compromises the datastore couldn't read its contents.

My issue is as follows. I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt a bunch of Strings (serialized objects turned into hex) using the same key, in an arbitrary order. This means that stream ciphers are out of the question, for key-reuse reasons. Which libraries, algorithms, or techniques will allow me to encrypt pieces of information independent of each other without weakness caused from using the same key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a block cipher (e.g. AES) in **[counter mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)**. In this mode each block can be encrypted / decrypted separately if you know it's counter.

Comment: Is it unsafe to have the counter stored someplace where a hacker could access it?

Comment: @user3078921 The counter don't need to be secret. It should however  be unique, so no two blocks are encrypted using the same counter and key.